# Reverb dropper post lever loose

Tags: seatpost, dropper

The lever to raise and lower my Rockshox Reverb Stealth 31.6 dropper post comes loose occasionally and can swing around 360 degrees. My seat is then stuck until I tight up the screw. When I re-tighten the screw, the lever works again and the dropper post works fine. However, I don't want to do this on the trail obviously. Does anyone know how I can prevent this problem from reoccurring?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A drop of threadlocker such as Blue Loctite 242 on the screw will keep it from coming loose.

Comment: Thanks. And the Blue Loctite 242 is OK to use even if the screw is intended to be loosened / tightened to adjust the location of the lever? And the threadlocker won't leak into the line or anything like that? I might be over analyzing it. Thanks again.

Comment: Blue Loctite allows threaded fasteners to be undone. Red 271 is the stuff that is meant to be permanent. You will need to clean the threads and reapply if you remove the screw to change the lever position You only need a tiny drop on the thread, so it won’t get into anything else.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.